# Infinite loop using string.substr(post,len)

Tags: c++, string, while-loop

Could you figure out why it keeps looping infinitely in the console? The programmer's supposed to list out each character of a user-inserted string and next to each unique character, in brackets, it's supposed to display the number of times that character occurs in the string... no idea why.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string input;
  cout << "input string: " , cin >> input;
  sort (input.begin() , input.end());
  while (!input.empty()) {
    int j{1}, i{0};
    while (input.at(i) == input.at(i+1)) {
      j++;
      i++;
    }
    cout << input.at(i) << " (" << j << "), ";
    input.substr(i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`string::substr()` is not in-place](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)

Comment: oh wow it's supposed to be ```string = string.substr(post,len)``` thanks
it throws an std::out of range error now ...

Comment: alright I got it now, thanks

Comment: @Biaaach `string::at()` performs bounds checking, and will raise an exception if given an index that is out of bounds. `input.at(i+1)` will go out of bounds when `i` reaches the last character of `input`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am aware, but how would one go about fixing that without using tail recursion?

Comment: Do your own bounds checking and don't use `at()` at all, or simply don't loop to the very last character.

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
input.substr(i);
```

does not change the object `input` itself.

So, either you will have an infinite loop if for some index `i` `input.at(i)` is not equal to `input.at(i+1)`, or you can have an exception out of range because `i + 1` can be equal to `input.size()`.

From the description of the member function `at`

> Throws: out_of_range if pos >= size().

The program can be implemented in different ways. For example the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "input string: ";
    std::string input;
      
    std::cin >> input;
      
    std::sort( input.begin() , input.end() );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); )
    {
        size_t j = input.find_first_not_of( input[i], i );
        
        if ( j == std::string::npos ) j = i + 1;
        
        if ( i != 0 ) std::cout << ", ";
        std::cout << input[i] << " (" << j - i << ")";

        i = j;
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
input string: Hello
H (1), e (1), l (2), o (1)
```

Or you can use the standard container `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` as for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "input string: ";
    std::string input;
      
    std::cin >> input;
      
    std::map<char, size_t> m;
    
    for ( const auto &c : input )
    {
        ++m[c];
    }

    bool first = true;
    for ( const auto &p : m )
    {
        if ( !first  ) std::cout << ", ";
        std::cout << p.first << " (" << p.second << ")";
        first = false;
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

If you want that characters of the inputted string were output in the order in which they are present in the string then the program can look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "input string: ";
    std::string input;
      
    std::cin >> input;
      
    auto less = [&input]( const auto &c1, const auto &c2 )
    {
        return input.find( c1 ) < input.find( c2 );
    };
    
    std::map<char, size_t, decltype( less )> m( less );
    
    for ( const auto &c : input )
    {
        ++m[c];
    }
    
    bool first = true;
    
    for ( const auto &p : m  )
    {
        if ( !first  ) std::cout << ", ";
        std::cout << p.first << " (" << p.second << ")";
        first = false;
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Or without changing the original string and without using an additional container the program can look the following way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "input string: ";
    std::string input;
      
    std::cin >> input;
      
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); i++ )
    {
        size_t j = 0;
        
        while ( j != i && input[j] != input[i] ) j++;
        
        if ( j == i )
        {
            size_t count = 1;
            while ( ++j < input.size() )
            {
                if ( input[j] == input[i]  ) ++count;
            }
            if ( i != 0  ) std::cout << ", ";
            std::cout << input[i] << " (" << count << ")";
        }
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
input string: elephant
e (2), l (1), p (1), h (1), a (1), n (1), t (1)
```

Comment: There is no undefined behavior, since `input.at(i+1)` will raise an exception. You might be thinking of `string::operator[]` instead, which prior to C++11 would indeed have undefined behavior for an out-of bounds-index.  But since C++11 onwards, `operator[]` allows `index==size()`, but `string::at()` does not.

Comment: argh, then I've got this all thought out incorrectly.. gotta be a better way to write this code..

Comment: @VladfromMoscow that's very conclusive thanks a bunch

Comment: @VladfromMoscow is there a particular reason why you're using size_t instead of unsigned int?

Comment: @Biaaach In general the type unsigned int can be not large enough to store values of the type std::string::size_type.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thanks, btw the last program you wrote out doesn't achieve the desired result if the word has the same character occur at different places in the word; example input: elephant

Comment: @VladfromMoscow that was fast thx vladimir.. have you worked for IRIS POWER LP by any chance?

Comment: @Biaaach I am unemployed. Nobody suggests me a job because it seems I am too  low-qualified.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow oh haha I thought you were some 60+ yearold I found on linkedin, you should get a university degree or some fast-track alternative

Comment: @Biaaach Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  // Get input string from the user
  string input;
  cout << "input string: ";
  cin >> input;

  // Sort the characters in the input string
  sort(input.begin(), input.end());

  // Count and display occurrences of each character
  while (!input.empty()) {
    int count{1}, i{0};

    // Count consecutive occurrences of a character
    while (i < input.size() - 1 && input.at(i) == input.at(i + 1)) {
      count++;
      i++;
    }

    // Display the character and its count
    cout << input.at(i) << " (" << count << "), ";

    // Remove counted characters from the string
    input = input.substr(i + 1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```